# Pushing getCurrentPosition() values into array but cannot console log elements of the array

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I've wrapped the geolocation API in the getLocation() function and am returning an array. However, when I try to access the specific elements of the array, I am getting undefined. I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

```
 const getLocation = function () {
        const arrLocations = [];
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            arrLocations.push(position.coords.latitude)
            arrLocations.push(position.coords.longitude)
        });
        return arrLocations;
    }
    const coord = getLocation();
    console.log(coord);
    console.log(coord[0]);
```

I've also tried to wrap the geolocation in a promise *just in case* there is some async happening with getCurrentPosition. The call returns undefined. (I'm not sure if I've written the promise right. I'm relatively new to JavaScript):

```
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const arrLocations = [];
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            arrLocations.push(position.coords.latitude)
            arrLocations.push(position.coords.longitude)
        });

        if (!arrLocations) {
            resolve(arrLocations);
        }
        else {
            reject();
        }
    })
        .then(function (arr) {
            return arr;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(`Something went wrong: ${e}`);
        });
```

Why is the element in the array returning undefined? And why is the promise returning undefined? Thanks!

Comment: If you try to log `arrLocations` from within `getLocation()`, it returns empty too...So you might want to start from there

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm getting the coordinates as I expect them. I put a console.log before the return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, which is why your first snippet doesn't work. You are returning and trying to log `arrLocations` before the async function has pushed anything. Using the promise in your second idea is a good intuition, it just needs a little tweaking.

Here's one way. Just `resolve` the array you want and take advantage of `getCurrentPosition`'s second parameter for an error call back to reject if needed. (you'll probably just get the error in a SO snippet):

```js
const getLocation = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => resolve([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]),
      (error) => reject(error)
    );
  })
}

// to use it:

getLocation()
  .then(arrLocations => console.log(arrLocations))
  .catch(err => console.log("there was an error: ", err))
```